# How to retrieve the link where AWS stored the image while using paperclip in Rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, rails-api

I have a rails-api in which I'm using paperclip to store the images and these images are getting stored on an S3 bucket.

This is the heroku log when I do a upload.

```
[paperclip] saving /feeds/images/000/000/025/original/test.png
2016-08-10T07:53:14.814789+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 200 0.480788 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"",:content_length=>589015,:content_type=>"image/png",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: test.png,:key=>"feeds/images/000/000/025/original/test.png")
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the link where this image is stored that is, **/feeds/images/000/000/025/original/test.png** and store it in my database for future downloads. Can someone point out to how I can access this key field?

I know S3 will save it at a default location each time like /model/object/000/000/(id of new record)/original/file_name, but I want to access the exact location where it has stored the image and not just make a conjecture.

**EDIT 2**

The problem of retrieving has solved but storing the links is still kind of shaky.

This is my method where I'm taking in the image

```
def create
id = params[:uid]
msg = params[:message]
img = params[:image]
feed = Feed.new({user_id: id, message: msg, like_count: 0, comment_count: 0, image: img})
feed.imageurl = feed.image.url(:medium)
feed.smallimageurl = feed.image.url(:thumb)
if feed.save
  render json: feed.as_json(only:[:id]), status:201
else
  render json: {errors: "Could not create post"}, status: 422
end
end
```

> When I upload any image it's storing the link as 
>   "http://s3.amazonaws.com/example/feeds/images//medium/458989879.jpg?"

See how the /000/000/026 is missing in between images and medium?

> However when I do this
>   Feed.find(26).image.url(:medium)

"http://s3.amazonaws.com/example/feeds/images/000/000/026/thumb/458989879.jpg?"

I know where the problem lies, it's that I need to store the image link after it's been stored to S3 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip provides this for you. The method is likely to be:

```
Feed.find(12345).image.url
```

You can get a list of the styles with:

```
Feed.find(12345).image.styles
```

... and the URL for a particular one of those with:

```
Feed.find(12345).image.url(:thumb)
```

Comment: That worked, is there a way to get the medium and thumb images I saved as well?

Comment: Hey, I edited the question. Can you take a look at edit2? Thanks!

Comment: Just save the instance of feed before reading the URL -- the URL depends on the id, which is unknown until you issue the save.

Comment: In fact, I would not use feed.imageurl or feed.smallimageurl at all -- you can read them both anyway without storing them.

Comment: But how can you return them as json? Can you somehow return it along with render json: feed.as_json(only:[:id]), status:201 ? Saving the feed work. You have been great help! Thanks :)